# Managing AWS Storage Gateway snapshots via API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-storage-gateway

I'm trying to write a tool which manages Amazon AWS snapshots automatically according to some very simple rules. These snapshots are created on a schedule set up in Amazon Storage Gateway, and show up as you'd expect in the web interface for that tool.

The Storage Gateway API only has operations for snapshots as far as the snapshot schedule goes. EC2 is the API which talks about snapshots. The problem is that if I DescribeSnapshots through that API I see many many hundreds of snapshots, but none of them have volume IDs which match the volume IDs of the snapshots created from Storage Gateway. They're just random public snapshots which I'm not interested in.

So I guess Storage Gateway snapshots are different somehow, but is there a way to use any of Amazon's APIs to list and manipulate them?

EDIT: Interestingly, they do show up in the EC2 web control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a top tip: the snapshots are there, just make sure you're looking for them using the right function. In this case, my novitiate in Clojure is still in effect and I tried to use `contains?` to search for an item in a sequence. Again. But it doesn't work like that, it looks for keys in collections which means over sequences it wants a number and will tell you if there's an item at that index or not. Even more fun, pass it a sequence and a string and it won't bat an eyelid, it just says `false`.

Oh and Amazon's not always consistent with capitalisation of volume IDs either, so make sure you lowercase everything before you compare it. That bit's actually relevant to AWS rather than me stubbornly misinterpreting the documentation of a core function.